# Does iOS simulator in Xcode allow AppleID sign in?

Tags: ios, icloud, apple-id, xcode

I am interested in using iCloud for Windows for syncing bookmarks between Windows browsers (as a replacement for Xmarks, which is shutting down). I installed iCloud for Windows and used my AppleID to log in, but it said I needed to first use an iOS device. I do not have an iPhone or iPad, nor intend to have, so maybe the iOS simulator in Xcode could be enough for this purpose of mine. So my question is: does Xcode's iOS simulator allow me to sign in my AppleID account? Or does it work "offline", account-free?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to sign-in to iCloud via iOS Simulator. Simply launch the Settings app and click on **Sign in to your iPhone** to log into iCloud.

[image] [image]

Comment: Doesn't work. After entering correct username/password, it always shows alert "iCloud: User name or password is incorrect.". Yes, I double checked my password, and tried multiple times. (Using iOS 13.3 iPhone 11 Pro Max simulator.)

Comment: @alizaliz I can sign in on iPad Pro emulator (3rd generation) iOS 13.3.

Comment: Note, need to log into icloud.com first and accept terms if haven't already done so with that account. https://stackoverflow.com/a/30634478/1032372

Comment: @shim you my saver. I searching this answer several days. I cant understand "Why I cannot sign_in in simulator?" And only and first thing it is accept that F### terms

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same issue several times on 2 different machines.
I solved it by going to icloud.com and sign in, accept the terms and conditions and when I tried logging in again, it worked.

Hope it works for you also.